# type 'Color' is not a subtype of type 'MaterialColor' error in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

**> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY

> ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> following _TypeError was thrown building Builder: type 'Color' is not
> a subtype of type 'MaterialColor'
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:   MaterialApp
> file:///D:/FlutterExercise/FlutterExercise/07/spanishaudioplayer/lib/main.dart:9:12
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      new _HomePageState (package:spanishaudioplayer/HomePage.dart:22:35)
> #1      HomePage.createState (package:spanishaudioplayer/HomePage.dart:7:35)
> #2      new StatefulElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4584:24)
> #3      StatefulWidget.createElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:916:38) ...     Normal
> element mounting (166 frames)
> #169    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3541:14)
> #170    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6094:32) ...     Normal
> element mounting (300 frames)
> #470    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3541:14)
> #471    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3306:18)
> #472    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1182:16)
> #473    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1153:5)
> #474    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree. (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1095:18)
> #475    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2647:19)
> #476    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1094:13)
> #477    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:934:7)
> #478    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget. (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:915:7) (elided 11 frames
> from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and
> dart:async-patch)
>
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> W/InputMethodManager(14486): startInputReason = 8
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14486): getExtractedText on inactive
> InputConnection W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14486): getTextBeforeCursor
> on inactive InputConnection V/ActivityThread(14486): Finishing stop of
> ActivityRecord{801579c token=android.os.BinderProxy@63e470c
> {com.example.spanishaudioplayer/com.example.spanishaudioplayer.MainActivity}}
> W/libEGL  (14486): EGLNativeWindowType 0x76efee7010 disconnect failed
> W/libEGL  (14486): EGLNativeWindowType 0x7713667010 disconnect failed
> V/ActivityThread(14486): Handle window ActivityRecord{801579c
> token=android.os.BinderProxy@63e470c
> {com.example.spanishaudioplayer/com.example.spanishaudioplayer.MainActivity}}
> visibility: false**

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'HomePage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Spanish Audio Numbers',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
        ),
        home: HomePage(),
      );
    }
  }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//HomePage.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'NumberAudio.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
  }

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    AudioCache audioPlayer = AudioCache();
    List<NumberAudio> audioList = [
      NumberAudio("one.wav", Colors.red, "one"),
      NumberAudio("two.wav", Colors.blue, "two"),
      NumberAudio("three.wav", Colors.pink, "three"),
      NumberAudio("four.wav", Colors.orange, "four"),
      NumberAudio("five.wav", Colors.purple, "five"),
      NumberAudio("six.wav", Colors.cyan, "six"),
      NumberAudio("seven.wav", Colors.green, "seven"),
      NumberAudio("eight.wav", Colors.grey, "eight"),
      NumberAudio("nine.wav", Colors.yellow, "nine"),
      NumberAudio("ten.wav", Colors.black, "ten"),
    ];
    play(String audioFile) async {
      audioPlayer.play(audioFile);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Spanish Numbers',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          //backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image(
                image: AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                  ),
                  itemCount: audioList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text(
                        audioList[index].buttonTitle,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      color: audioList[index].buttonColor,
                      onPressed: () {
                        play(audioList[index].audioFile);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//NumberAudio.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NumberAudio {
    String audioFile;
    MaterialColor buttonColor;
    String buttonTitle;
    NumberAudio(String audioFile, MaterialColor buttonColor, String buttonTitle) {
      this.audioFile = audioFile;
      this.buttonColor = buttonColor;
      this.buttonTitle = buttonTitle;
    }
}
```

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGfKS.png

Answer (score 3):

`Color` is not a subtype of `MaterialColor`.

```
theme: ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
),
```

Here `primarySwatch` has type `MaterialColor` but you put `Colors.teal` which has type `Color`.

If you want to create instance of `MaterialColor` please try something like that:

```
   static const MaterialColor colorPrimarySwatch = const MaterialColor(
    0xFFFFFFFF,
    const <int, Color>{
      50: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      100: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      200: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      300: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      400: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      500: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      600: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      700: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      800: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      900: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    },
  );
```

Don't forget to change `buttonColor` type from `MaterialColor` to `Color`

```
class NumberAudio {
    String audioFile;
    Color buttonColor;
    String buttonTitle;

    NumberAudio(String audioFile, Color buttonColor, String buttonTitle) {
      this.audioFile = audioFile;
      this.buttonColor = buttonColor;
      this.buttonTitle = buttonTitle;
    }
}
```